# Tuples as Key in Map, how to retrieve value?

Tags: scala, tuples

Imagine the following (pseudo) class:

```
class Board(rows: Int, cols: Int)
{
  val fields = Map[(Int, Int), Field] // Position is a tuple

  def getField(position: (Int, Int)): Field
  {
    fields(position)
  }
}
```

How could I do this? I could create a type like:

```
type Position = (Int, Int)
```

and then `val fields = Map[Position, Field]`

Could that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors, but once you fix them, it should work. Using `String` instead of `Field` (since I don't know the definiton of Field), you can write this in Scala REPL and see it work:

```
scala> val fields: Map[(Int, Int), String] = Map((1,2) -> "a", (3,4) -> "b")
fields: Map[(Int, Int),String] = Map((1,2) -> a, (3,4) -> b)

scala> def getField(position: (Int, Int)) = fields(position)
getField: (position: (Int, Int))String

scala> getField((1,2))
res1: String = a
```